# How to connect mini-itx with atx 2-pin block to 24-pin ATX12V

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, atx, mini-itx

I have a mini-itx motherboard that has a 2-pin internal 12V DC-in power connector (Motherboard [manual](http://www.jetwayipc.com/Manual/G03-NF591-F.pdf)) (+12V DC)

I also have a power supply with 24-pin motherboard connector.

Now I want to connect them together.

I am thinking of connecting pins 15 and 16 together to make power supply boot up
(Pin 15 - Ground, Pin 16 - Power on)
and then use a cable to connect pins 10 and 24 to the mini-itx motherboard)
(Pin 10 - +12V, Pin 24 - Ground).

Motherboard has (Pin 1 - Ground, Pin 2 - +12V DC_IN)

So I will connect ATX Pin 10 to MB Pin 1 and ATX Pin 24 to MB Pin 2.

Will this setup work or there is something else to be done?

P.S. I don't have all the correct cables, but I have 2 Male-ending cables that look like a good fit. I wanted to connect an ATX Male cable to a CPU Male cable (obviously I will trace the lines) and connect that to the MB. I have "some #18 Gauge Galvanized wire" that I want to use, as well as electrical tape of course. Wire definitely fits in cables' male connectors quiet snugly.

Answer (score 1):

Have to answer my own question.

This type of setup will work fine from my experience.
I did connect the pins as I have described in the question.

Everything works smoothly. I power up power supply first, then boot the pc - nothing changes in that regard.

The only change for me is that when I decide to power my PC off I do turn off the power supply just in case.

I did end up using #18 Gauge Galvanized wire, carefully taping it with electric tape.

Answer (score 0):

I also have a Jetway motherboard, for which I have the same challenge -- a 2 pin 12 volt power input on the board without a 24 pin PSU connection.

The OP is correct, pin 15 and 16 connected on the 24 pin connector from the PSU will make the PSU come alive, but my bench test told me it need to stay connected to stay powered -- ***Wiring a toggle switch to those two pins and mounting it on the outside of the case will turn the device power on and off without having to pull the cord*** (I'm using a flex PSU that doesn't have an integral switch, as many ATX PSU's do).

Props to the OP for providing the pin numbers, adding the switch will bring it home (depending on the PSU you're using).

NOTE: Some Jetway motherboards have "AT_MODE" jumper pins that allow you to select between "AT" and "ATX" power modes. If you set it to "ATX" mode you'll have to turn on the PSU with the toggle switch, then hit the power button connected to the front panel headers on the motherboard, then the computer will start. If you set the AT_MODE to "AT" then the motherboard will power up as soon as power is introduced - meaning the motherboard will power up as soon as you turn on the PSU using the toggle switch.